# Prolog: Display each element of each sublist

Tags: prolog

I have a large list of smaller sublists like:

```
 [ [005,Chester,100],[001,Bob,99],[002,Andy,77] ]
```

I'm trying to make a display "function" that loops through the entire list and displays like:

```
 No.1: ID="005", Name="Chester", Grade=100
 No.2: ID="001", Name="Bob", Grade=99
 No.3: ID="002", Name="Andy", Grade=77
```

thinking in prolog is hard enough but i'm struggling with recursive thinking. any assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having just recursion to handle data structures it's - I think - the main problem of Prolog.

This lack of expressiveness on data structures that we *know* are of appropriate shape, has spurred both extensions (like loops in B-Prolog) and languages - like [Picat](http://www.picat-lang.org/).

Anyway, plain Prolog it's powerful enough to solve your problem:

```
show_records(L) :-
    forall(nth1(N, L, E), format('No.~d:ID="~s",Name="~s",Grade="~d"~n', [N|E])).
```

yields

```
?- show_records([ ['005','Chester',100],['001','Bob',99],['002','Andy',77] ]).
No.1:ID="005",Name="Chester",Grade="100"
No.2:ID="001",Name="Bob",Grade="99"
No.3:ID="002",Name="Andy",Grade="77"
true.
```

Comment: That's a very nice little solution.

Comment: That's a very nice little solution `:)`

Comment: thanks. i had to change ~s to ~a for it to work with my strings in unix. on swi-prolog it worked perfectly. guess it's cause my strings were stored with single quotes?

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza: sorry, can't understand. I'm using Ubuntu, and latest SWI-Prolog... I tried also ~a, and double quotes, like "005", seems all combinations are working...

Comment: cool. it's working fine so no big deal. it just gave me "Illegal argument to format sequence ~s" error so i changed it to ~a. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

My answer is written with SWI-Prolog in mind, and detailed information on any built-in predicates I mention can be had by [searching the documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/). However, I think everything I say here holds for other prominent Prolog implementations. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

In Prolog, we work with *predicates* rather than *functions*, (or, we only use functions that return truth-values). I will use the following predicate to refer to your example list in my Prolog queries:

```
ex([ [005,"Chester",100],[001,"Bob",99],[002,"Andy",77] ]).
```

For writing formatted text to the standard output stream, we'll use the the predicate `format/2`. It's signature is `format(+Format, :Arguments)`, where `Format` is an atom including special sequences to facilitate interpolation. Escape sequences begin with the tilde, `~`, and the full menu can be found in the SWI-Prolo [documentation on `format/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2). `Arguments` is a list of prolog terms used to replace the sequences in `Format`. In this example, we'll only need `~w`, which writes an argument and `~n`, which writes a newline. As a general example: E.g.,

```
?- format('Write ~w, then ~w, followed by ~w~n~n', ['this', 'that', 'the other']).
Write this, then that, followed by the other

true.
```

You're representing a person as a list of the form `[ID, Name, Grade`], so we only need to write a predicate that will let us add the `N` in "No.N", and then we can use the person-list for the rest of the arguments to `format/2`:

```
display_person(N, Person) :-
    format('No.~w: ID="~w", Name="~w", Grade=~w~n', [N|Person]).
```

In the second argument of `format/2`, `N` is prefixed as the head of the argument list. We can test the predicate like so:

```
?- ex([P|Ps]), display_person(1, P).
No.1: ID="5", Name="Chester", Grade=100
P = [5, "Chester", 100],
Ps = [[1, "Bob", 99], [2, "Andy", 77]].
```

That takes care of displaying each individual person-list. Now we just need to iterate through your list of people and display each member. We'll need a two-place predicate in order to keep track of the increasing value of `N` for the 'No.N' portion of the display, but we only need a one-place predicate to pass the list to the display predicate. This requirement leads us to use the common pattern of using a front-end predicate supported by an auxiliary predicate:

display_people(People) :-
    display_people(1, People).   %% Initializes the call to `display_people/2` with the starting value 1

display_people(_, []).
display_people(N, [Person|People]) :-
    display_person(N, Person),
    M is N+1,
    display_people(M, People).

Running a test using the list from `ex/1`:

```
?- ex(Ps), display_people(Ps).
No.1: ID="5", Name="Chester", Grade=100
No.2: ID="1", Name="Bob", Grade=99
No.3: ID="2", Name="Andy", Grade=77
Ps = [[5, "Chester", 100], [1, "Bob", 99], [2, "Andy", 77]] ;
false.
```

However, the pattern `p([X|Xs]) :- q(X), p(Xs)` is just what the `maplist/n` predicate is for, so we can save ourselves a bit of typing, and arguably make the declarative meaning of the program clearer by writing the following:

```
display_people(People) :-
    length(People, NumPeople),
    numlist(1, NumPeople, Nums),
    maplist(display_person, Nums, People).
```

`numlist(Low, High, Nums)` returns a list, `Nums`, with values from `Low` to `High`. In the preceding definition, `maplist(display_person, Nums, People)` will essentially call `display_person(N, P)` for each pair of `N` in `Nums` and `P` in `People`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only to answer aBathologist about the use of `foldl`. I'm copying verbatim his `display_person/2` predicate:

```
display_person(N, Person) :-
    format('No.~w: ID="~w", Name="~w", Grade=~w~n', [N|Person]).
```

Then a little adapter that will increment the `N` in the previous predicate (and puts the arguments in the correct order):

```
display_person(Person,N,NextN) :-
    display_person(N,Person),
    NextN is N+1.
```

And use `foldl`:

```
display_people(People) :-
    foldl(display_person,People,1,_).
```

If

```
`People=[P1,P2,...,Pn]`
```

then `foldl(display_person,People,1,Rn)` is equivalent to:

```
display_person(People,1,R1),
display_person(People,R1,R2),
...
display_person(People,R(n-1),Rn).
```

The use of `foldl` in this fashion avoids going through the list once to get its length. But, on the other hand, you need an adapter predicate.

Anyway, better or worse in this case is not really important! `foldl` is just another trick that's good to know and that can sometimes make your code cleaner.

Comment: Very helpful. I would think CapelliC's answer takes the cake for concision and efficiency, but I am very grateful for the tutorial on using `foldl` in a context that (finally!) makes its operation clear to me. I've been totally missing the way that the last two arguments to `foldl` are supposed to work, but now I see! As you say, its another (I think really important?) trick. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion. First, write a predicate that displays each entry by using Prolog's [format predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2), which is a printf-equivalent, and pass the list directly as the argument. Second, map the first predicate over the list using [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/2).

Comment: `maplist/2` might not do, since the OP wants the lines to be prepended by a `No.X: ` field. So a `foldl` (with the line number as accumulator) might be more appropriate.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm embarrassed to say that I've never yet really grasped the practical use of `foldl` would you be kind enough to give me an example of how one would use `foldl` in this context? Thanks!

Comment: @aBathologist I made an answer just for you!